# How to convert each row values of a column to a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a df,

```
               Name  Grade
                A    K,1
                B    1,2,3
                C    3,8
          df.dtypes
          Name     object
          Grade    object
          dtype: object
```

I want to have Grade as list like,

```
               Name  Grade
                A    [K,1]
                B    [1,2,3]
                C    [3,8]
```

Then, I have a list

```
           List = [2,3]
```

I would like to extract names that has at least one value from List in Grade from df.

```
         Expected Output = Name  Grade
                            B    [1,2,3] 
                            C    [3,8]
```

Comment: `object` is the "generic catch all" type of pandas. What do you have now in Grade? strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way , notice after split the number still keep as string type

```
df=df[df.Grade.str.split(',',expand=True).isin(['2','3']).any(1)]
df
  Name  Grade
1    B  1,2,3
2    C    3,8
#df.Grade=df.Grade.str.split(',')
```

Comment: How do I make 2,3 to ['2','3']?

Comment: @JenniferTherese run the marked line df.Grade=df.Grade.str.split(',')